# Enqueue less file not working in child theme?

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

In my child theme I have:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    //Load Bootstrap and 3rd Party
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2css', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css' );
    // Load our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'less-style', '/css/style.less' );
}
```

All the external stylesheets at the top load correctly but the less stylesheet causes 500 error.

The only other time I've done this was in a non-child theme and I had:

```
function themename_scripts() {
    // Add custom fonts, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-fonts', themename_fonts_url(), array(), null );
    // Add Genericons, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.2' );
    //Load Bootstrap and 3rd Party
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css', array( 'themename-style' ), '20141010' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array( 'themename-style' ), '20141010' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-select2', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css', array( 'themename-style' ), '20141010' );
    // Load our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'less-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.less' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_scripts' );
```

And this worked just fine when it wasn't a child theme. What am I missing in the child-theme on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` gets the current template (child in this case) directory, eg

```
// Load our main stylesheet.
wp_enqueue_style( 'less-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.less' );
```