# enqueue_parent_style

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to change my @import style.css to wp_enqueue_style for my child themes. I added the following into my functions.php child theme and it returns a 500 error. I looked at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnpyM6h9jE0) and pretty much followed it to the T. I also looked at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207494/enqueue-less-file-not-working-in-child-theme) but the answer didn't make sense to me. I am pretty new at this so I just couldn't make the jump.

```
    function child_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri () .'/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_styles' );
```

Any help would be good here as I would rather enqueue scripts the faster and better way. I am testing this on my local before activating it live, so I can't give the site URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you change your `wp_enqueue_style` to the one below it will work perfectly. This is the way I do it inside my own `functions.php` file.

```
function wpse_scripts() {
    // Theme Stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_scripts');
```

Although you can do it the way your doing it, it's just you've added a `/` before your `style.css` and you don't need that. By adding the `/` your script is looking for a folder called `style.css`

```
function wpse_scripts() {
    // Theme Stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_scripts');
```

The way your doing it would be done like this

Here are some places to start when changing your `functions.php` in your child theme.

[**Child Theme**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it but it still didn't work. I am using a WPMU site with multiple themes. Would this cause issues?

Comment: Have you tried the bottom solution I gave you? If not then I'm not too sure as I've not really done much on WPMU

Comment: Yeah, I tried both snippets and neither work. I thought they would as they look pretty standard. Do you think there is a need to identify the exact parent theme I am looking to use as there are several themes in the setup?

Comment: You try try identifying the exact parent theme whether it will work or not though I have no idea my friend. Best of luck with this

Comment: Some of the child theme functions were messing with the parent functions. Once I removed them your solution worked.

Comment: I was going to tell you to check your parent theme this morning (where I am) to see if anything is conflicting with the child theme xD Well atleast you got it sorted